# jquery define timeout when calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, joomla, timeout

I am stuck on getting a timeout working. I already have a working code but it seems to me the wrong way to do it.

## Working code but probably not the best:

```
/* Autosave */
// On load we hide all autosave messages.
$('.jform_params_autosave-cg').hide();
// Below is the function that handles the autosave.
$.fn.autoSave = function(){
  // We remove the autosave message from it's place defined by the xml and add it to the system message container.
  var autosavemessage = $('.jform_params_autosave-cg');
  autosavemessage.detach();
  autosavemessage.appendTo('#system-message-container');
  // Now we show the message.
  $('.jform_params_autosave-cg').show();
  // Here we save the extension.
  Joomla.submitbutton('module.apply');
}
// On change of the below elements we run the autosave.
//------------------------------------------//
// DUPLICATE AUTOSAVE FUNCTION BELOW
//------------------------------------------//
// Autosave: Theme Selection
$("#jform_params_theme_selection").change(function() {
  $.fn.autoSave();
});
// Autosave: Add Content
$("a.group-add.btn.btn-mini.button.btn-success").click(function() {
  setTimeout(
    function()
    {
      $.fn.autoSave();
    }, 5000);
});
```

## The Function:

```
$.fn.autoSave = function(){
  // We remove the autosave message from it's place defined by the xml and add it to the system message container.
  var autosavemessage = $('.jform_params_autosave-cg');
  autosavemessage.detach();
  autosavemessage.appendTo('#system-message-container');
  // Now we show the message.
  $('.jform_params_autosave-cg').show();
  // Here we save the extension.
  Joomla.submitbutton('module.apply');
}
```

## The Function Call

```
$("#jform_params_theme_selection").change(function() {
  $.fn.autoSave();
});
```

## The Function Call with Timeout

```
$("a.group-add.btn.btn-mini.button.btn-success").click(function() {
  setTimeout(
    function()
    {
      $.fn.autoSave();
    }, 5000);
});
```

## What do I want to achieve

1. Make the Timeout inside the function.
2. Define the timeout when calling the function.

With defining I mean calling it something like `$.fn.autoSave(5000);` or `$.fn.autoSave().timeout(500);`

I have been trying to get a working code but so far no luck. Will keep updating this post whenever I get more success or details to add.

## Thanks everyone for helping.

Any link to existing SO questions will also be appreciated as I might be googling for the wrong key words.

Comment: You are looking for "Create a Plugin" check here https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak Thank you for the link. Indeed that is what I am looking for. Unfortunately in the quick glance I took over the page there is no example with timeout. Going to read it from A to Z but don't think it is on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is the modified version of your function. Now it has optional timeout parameter. You can use it like

`$('selector').autoSave(5000)` or `$('selector').autoSave()`

```js
$.fn.autoSave = function(timeout) {
  function doIt() {
    // We remove the autosave message from it's place defined by the xml and add it to the system message container.
    var autosavemessage = $('.jform_params_autosave-cg');
    autosavemessage.detach();
    autosavemessage.appendTo('#system-message-container');
    // Now we show the message.
    $('.jform_params_autosave-cg').show();
    // Here we save the extension.
    Joomla.submitbutton('module.apply');
    return this;
  }
  timeout = Number(timeout) || 0;
  var f = doIt.bind(this);
  if(timeout < 0) return f();
  setTimeout(f, timeout);
  return this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works directly. Would you mind explaining what the last 5 lines are doing? PS: In this case the selector was:       `$.fn.autoSave(5000);`

Comment: Sure, It wraps the current logic into an inner callback to get rid of writing same lines twice. Then it checks if timeout parameter is positive number. If not It calls main logic directly, otherwise it triggers a timeout for our inner callback.

Comment: @purple11111 Actually `$.fn.autoSave` is not a selector. It is calling plugin method directly. When you have a function in $.fn object, that mean you will be able to use the same function like `$('your_element_selector').yourFunction()`. It is plugin feature of jQuery

Comment: Ah oke. I am sure I will understand that after I read the link you gave from A to Z. Thanks man you really helped me out a lot here! With your piece of code it looks a lot better then duplicating the timeout! Have a great day!